# Why does if( union member) evaluate as True?

Tags: c, unions

```
 union Data {
   int i;
   char s[20];
   } data;

int main(){
   printf( "%lu\n", sizeof( data ) );
   for( int i = 0; i < 20; ++i ) {
     data.s[i] = 0;
   }
   data.i = 0;
   strcpy( data.s, "Hello World!");
   if( data.i ) {
       strcpy( data.s, "Farewell!");
   }
   printf( "%s\n", data.s );
```

Why does it respond with "Farewell"? I would expect `if( data.i )` to evaluate as `False`, but somehow it is evaluated as `True`.

Comment: `data.i` shares memory with `data.s`.  You cleared `data.i`, but then subsequently filled `data.s` with non-zero values, so `data.i` is no longer zero.

Comment: use a `struct` instead of an `union`

Comment: Curious: Why did code use `"%ld"` with `sizeof( )`?

Comment: To be mean: Because the compiler developer didn't make it say "Ha, ha,ha, now you die!". Accessing a member of a union that isn't the one last written (unless they have a common prefix) is undefined behavior. Anything can happen. Usually you simply get the bit pattern stored in the union interpreted as the other type as in your case.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow "Accessing a member of a union that isn't the one last written" sounds like a C++ thing.  Confident that applies to C as in this post?

Comment: @chux You are correct, that is a C++ thing.  It is legal, though perhaps ambiguously worded, in the C99 standard.  The C11 standard fixed this and added in a footnote clarifying its legality.  In the committee draft, it can be found in Section 6.5.2.3 footnote 95.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unlike a `struct`, all fields in a `union` overlap each other in memory.  So if you change one field, it affects all the others.

If you want the fields to be distinct from each other, declare a `struct` instead:

```
struct Data {
   int i;
   char s[20];
} data;
```